# Getting the row ID of a listview from a Android SQlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

I have created a listview which displays all the people in the database. But how do I get the row id of the one I select so I can pass that infomation to the next activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_game1);

    listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

    mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbAdapter.open();
    Cursor cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAll();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_NAME, DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    mDbAdapter.close();
    }
```

Which displays
[displays http://i.minus.com/iGEtGKGyF1Wgc.png](http://i.minus.com/iGEtGKGyF1Wgc.png)

Now I want to click on a name get that row id from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` on your `Listview` then you will get the id of the selected item (item id start from 0 but Database _id column is start from 1 so you should send `id+1`, please confirm this).

And send the id using intents.

Answer (score 2):

Use this API call: `cursorAdapter.getItemId(positionInListView)`

Comment: i think its getItemId not getitemId

Answer (score 0):

You have to register implement and add an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to the list so you can react when an item was clicked. The item id will be passed into the onListItemClick() method of the OnItemClickListener.